Clearing present simple and present perfect with since
Kindly don't get me wrong that I am asking that expressed question about since with present simple and present perfect.For present simple , we just show actions at the present situation.Present perfect that related to the past.It is okay.Here I want to point is to clear my mind and I would like to dare to use that usage with confidence.I am not judging about usage , I am trying to divide clearly that usage of since with present simple so as to dare to use..How to I divide that
A. If I want to show action with since, I just use the present perfect. For example

I have gone from market since My mother have called me up.

They have moved down town since their uncle invited them.


B. If I want to show a state , for the state, I can use present simple in place of present perfect with since. Because present simple is used for general truth. It was, now it is and future it will be. For example

The sun rises in the East and sets in the West.

The cow gives milk us.


I want to say here is present simple also can imply the past. Also still true right now. I am okay and I have been okay , those are showing the state. I  am satisfied and I have been satisfied, they do the same. Moreover, I accept and I have accepted as well. The state does not need to show continuous form. It is used for simple form.
So if I want to show state I can use present simple with since. I am okay now means I was okay since something happened. I am satisfied now means I was satisfied since something happened. It does not make any difference because they are showing the state. So I want to divide and keep in mind, I want to show a state with since then I don't need to use present perfect and I can use present simple with since. That is how I divide and keep in mind. For example

I know that famous actress since she acted as a kid.

I accept that rule since they declared to use it.


No need to say my level, yes I know, but I need to say my level. My level is B1. Because I want to make good foundation for English that's why I am asking this my concept to make me clear myself.
Can I divide and use that concept?
In my question, I dont want to point out after since tenses. For example since simple past or since perfect tenses.I want to point out that simple present before since.

The different ways we use the word since in English are quite complicated and cover a wide range ("from that time" and "because" are just two possible meanings). It's obvious you're at the very beginning of the long process of learning English, so I suggest you put since aside and concentrate on basic verb tense forms for now.

Yes ,Thank you for your advice@FumbleFingers

Note that in contexts like Since he lost his job he has nothing to do all day the meaning of since is "ambiguous" in that although being idle definitely started when he lost his job, the because sense wouldn't always be implied.

In my question ,  I did not point out the tenses after since, since past simple or since prefect tenses.I want to point out the tense present simple before since. Can I use present simple tense above my question before since. @FumbleFingers

(5) and (6) would both be more natural  with the present perfect - I have known that actress since... and I have accepted that rule since.... I don't know why you are so determined to use the present tense with since!

Because I can't use "She has been satisfied since becoming tall. It makes me confused."  In stead of that  she is satisfied since becoming tall.  That is better , I don't understand ,  why? @Kate Bunting

It was explained to you (in answer to your question about that sentence) that it is wrong because it is an odd thing to say in English, not because of the tense. You have now asked several questions about tenses with 'since', and have been told several times that we don't normally use the present tense with it.

Oh! I get the point now.  Not because of tense but because of an odd thing to say English. Thank you madam , you are every time making me clear. @Kate Bunting

Note that sentences 1, 4 , 5 and 6 are not grammatical.  Also there's an error in Sentence 3. The words east and west when used as cardinal directions are not proper nouns, just common nouns, and should not be capitalised.

Please more examples so as to keep in mind and learn@Billy Kerr

To lift an explanation directly from Oxford dictionary, 'since' means "in the intervening period between the time mentioned and the time under consideration, typically the present".
So there is the possibility for two different tenses within a statement that uses since - an event in the past that marked the beginning of the period, and then the action or state that either exists or continues in the present.
Some good examples would be:

I have been learning since I was 11. ("have been" is perfect present tense, because the happiness continues. "I was 11" is an event in the past)
I am a lot happier since I left my job. ("I am" is present tense because it is a current state. "I left" is past because leaving the job was an event in the past)

Your examples:

I have gone from market since My mother have called me up.

This is grammatically incorrect and probably an incorrect use of "since". If by "I have gone" you mean "I left", this is a past event, so is the phone call. It's not a good context to use "since". You should probably just say "I left the market when my mother called me".

They have moved down town since their uncle invited them.

Again, "moved" is a past event, so this isn't good with since. You could say "they moved down town after their uncle invited them", or if you really wanted to use 'since', change it from a past event to a present perfect verb and say "they have lived down town since their uncle invited them".

I know that famous actress since she acted as a kid.

This is almost right - "I know" is a present condition, but "acted" is not really a past event. She might have acted for years. She might still be a kid.

I accept that rule since they declared to use it.

This would be better with "once", or "after", rather than "since". You have to also remember that "since" has a secondary meaning of because, and it could mean that in this example which changes the meaning entirely.

If I change sentence how it would be  "I know that famous actress since she played a kid's roll." @Astrabee

If I write "I have gone from market from when my mother have called me up." Is it possible to use, madam?@Astrabee
